# Generate point a certain distance along a polyline

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

It is as trivial to sample regularly along a line using `st_line_sample()`, as it is to calculate the middle point of a line using `st_point_on_surface()`. However, what I would like to do is to generate a single new point based on a given distance along a line from the first vertex. For example, given a line of length 200 metres of any geometry, return the XY coordinates along the line that is 55 metres from the start.

My question sounds similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922874/should-be-easy-distance-along-a-line-in-r), although it refers to calculating shortest paths (i.e., travelling salesman), which is different to what I am asking. It is more similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905515/leaflet-point-along-polyline-at-certain-distance), but the language is javascript and is as yet unanswered.

Comment: Hi! I think you can readapt the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987924/find-coordinates-x-distance-along-linestring/67999593?noredirect=1#comment120191484_67999593 If you want I can add a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I have enough from that linked question to solve my problem but if you wrote a similar answer to this question I would accept it.